# How do I do MultipartEntity with HttpPost in a background thread?

Tags: java, android

How do I do this code so that it sends in a background thread?

```
// TODO: Send image in background
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlString);

            try {
              MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
              entity.addPart("userfile", new FileBody(f));
              httppost.setEntity(entity);
              HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
              String sResponse;
              StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

              while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  s = s.append(sResponse); 
              }
              Log.d("Response", "Response: " + s);
            } 
            catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same way you do anything in a background thread -- start a thread to do it. On Android, you can use `AsyncTask` to execute stuff in the background and update the UI when done.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html